# div grid tab not in content

Tags: html, css

I use a php function to put my page content in the index.php, but when I use a grid (tab) in the content it goes out of the content borders.

I put a little bit of the code underneath, you can see the site here: (link deleted > problem solved)

Comment: can you clarify in images?

Comment: Reviewing your site i don't see anything wrong with out of placed content. Do you have a image for us with an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put your `.clearfix`  in the beginning of the `.content` .

If you place it after the tabs, the border will display correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Roberrt.

Why the downvote? I tried this solution in the developer toolbar, and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Non floated elements only takes height of their non-floated child or content.

Examples

**Situation 1:** *Non floated parent and non-floated child.* The parent element will take full height of it's child.

```css
div{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
</div>
```

---

**Situation 2:** *Non floated parent and but floated child.* Again the parent element is only taking height of not-floated child element(s) because the floating elements does not affect the size of the parent element.

```css
div{
  border:1px solid;
}
.float{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
  
  <p class=float>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
  
  <p class=float>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
</div>
```

---

**Situation 3:** *Floated parent and floated child.* Now this situation is actually a solution of the 2nd Situation, but this situation/solution is not best practice, Especially when you want parent to be centered align of it's parent.

Now why this situation is working? because floated elements will expand to contain it's floated child elements.

```css
div{
  border:1px solid;
  float:left;
}
.float{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p  class=float>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
  
  <p class=float>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
  
  <p class=float>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
</div>
```

---

---

Now how we can solve 2nd situation without using 3rd situation. The answer is The clear CSS property.

> The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to
>   floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared)
>   below them. The clear property applies to both floating and
>   non-floating elements.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Now How we can use `clear`?

The stone age solution, put an element at the bottom of parent element and give it `clearfix`. This is a good solution but every time you have to add an extra element. Worthless when you cannot edit your dynamic HTML.

```css
div.parent{
  border:1px solid;
}
.float{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
  
  <p class=float>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
  
  <p class=float>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
  
  
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

---

Now you don't want to add an extra element then let css3 do this job for you, create and element at the bottom of parent with `pseudo:after` element then assign it a job to clear floated elements.

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
div.parent{
  border:1px solid;
}
.float{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent clearfix">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
  
  <p class=float>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
  
  <p class=float>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis magnam, soluta nihil libero sapiente, ullam omnis ipsa adipisci, mollitia vero ea iste nam doloribus iusto voluptatum itaque, dicta fuga assumenda.</p>
  
</div>
```

**Sources**

1. [Clear CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear)
2. [What is a Clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-a-clearfix)

Answer (score 2):

Changes CSS use overflow: hidden; it recover box

```
.content {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.content {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it all happens because of the `float:left` you used on the `.tab3` . you either use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` or you use `float:left` on the content

not working ( as it is on your site )

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url(img/bg.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Ubuntu Light", Ubuntu, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.main {
  width: 676px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  clear: both;
}

.tab3 {
  width: calc(100%/ 3);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="side-heading">Habbo</div>
  Op deze pagina vind je de ins en outs van Habbo (Hotel) en Sulake. We bieden je gidsen aan waarin uitleg staat over de talentenmeter, de catalogus, de (oude) Habbo Staff en Moderators, Habbo Club en ga zo maar verder. Ook vind je hier de geschiedenis
  van Habbo. En informatie over het bedrijf achter Habbo, namelijk Sulake. Mis je iets op deze pagina? Neem dan contact op met de webmaster.
  <div class="space"></div>
  <a href="?page=habbo_burgerschap">
    <div class="tab3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="blocktitle">Habbo Burgerschap</div>
        <div class="blockimage" style="background-image:url(img/content/habbo_burgerschap.png)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="tab3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="blocktitle">Archievements</div>
        <div class="blockimage" style="background-image:url(img/bg.png)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="tab3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="blocktitle">Habbo Regels</div>
        <div class="blockimage" style="background-image:url(img/bg.png)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="tab3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="blocktitle">Habbo Games</div>
        <div class="blockimage" style="background-image:url(img/content/habbo_games.png)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

solution 1. inline-block

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url(img/bg.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Ubuntu Light", Ubuntu, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.main {
  width: 676px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  clear: both;
}

.tab3 {
  width: calc(100%/ 3);
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="side-heading">Habbo</div>
  Op deze pagina vind je de ins en outs van Habbo (Hotel) en Sulake. We bieden je gidsen aan waarin uitleg staat over de talentenmeter, de catalogus, de (oude) Habbo Staff en Moderators, Habbo Club en ga zo maar verder. Ook vind je hier de geschiedenis
  van Habbo. En informatie over het bedrijf achter Habbo, namelijk Sulake. Mis je iets op deze pagina? Neem dan contact op met de webmaster.
  <div class="space"></div>
  <a href="?page=habbo_burgerschap">
    <div class="tab3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="blocktitle">Habbo Burgerschap</div>
        <div class="blockimage" style="background-image:url(img/content/habbo_burgerschap.png)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="tab3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="blocktitle">Archievements</div>
        <div class="blockimage" style="background-image:url(img/bg.png)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="tab3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="blocktitle">Habbo Regels</div>
        <div class="blockimage" style="background-image:url(img/bg.png)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="tab3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="blocktitle">Habbo Games</div>
        <div class="blockimage" style="background-image:url(img/content/habbo_games.png)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

solution2 . float:left on content

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: url(img/bg.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Ubuntu Light", Ubuntu, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.main {
  width: 676px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
}

.tab3 {
  width: calc(100%/ 3);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="side-heading">Habbo</div>
  Op deze pagina vind je de ins en outs van Habbo (Hotel) en Sulake. We bieden je gidsen aan waarin uitleg staat over de talentenmeter, de catalogus, de (oude) Habbo Staff en Moderators, Habbo Club en ga zo maar verder. Ook vind je hier de geschiedenis
  van Habbo. En informatie over het bedrijf achter Habbo, namelijk Sulake. Mis je iets op deze pagina? Neem dan contact op met de webmaster.
  <div class="space"></div>
  <a href="?page=habbo_burgerschap">
    <div class="tab3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="blocktitle">Habbo Burgerschap</div>
        <div class="blockimage" style="background-image:url(img/content/habbo_burgerschap.png)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="tab3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="blocktitle">Archievements</div>
        <div class="blockimage" style="background-image:url(img/bg.png)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="tab3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="blocktitle">Habbo Regels</div>
        <div class="blockimage" style="background-image:url(img/bg.png)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="tab3">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="blocktitle">Habbo Games</div>
        <div class="blockimage" style="background-image:url(img/content/habbo_games.png)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

let me know if one of these 2 solutions worked for you