# Expand outer nested div to 100%

Tags: html, css

I have this code

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  width: 100%;
}

.outer div {
  float: left;
  background-color: #0000ff;

}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    test1    <br/> test1
  </div>
  <div>
    test2    <br/> test2
  </div> 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jcb5mdqa/

It looks like

[image]

but I want the outer to have a width of 100% like in .css written.

Expected result

[image]

What do I need to change?

Comment: Because all the content of .outer is floating, they are removed from the document flow. As a result, .outer is empty and not shown.

Comment: @Gerard thank you for explaination did not know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.outer` has width 100% already because it's a block element. It lacks height because the content is floated. To give `.outer` the height of the content, add `overflow: auto` to the class definition:

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  overflow: auto;
}

.outer div {
  float: left;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    test1    <br/> test1
  </div>
  <div>
    test2    <br/> test2
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `clearfix`

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  width: 100%;
}

.outer div {
  float: left;
  background-color: #0000ff;

}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer clearfix">
  <div>
    test1    <br/> test1
  </div>
  <div>
    test2    <br/> test2
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: @Toshi I answered similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44428121/6670723) , you can check it for more details.

Comment: isn't `overflow: auto;` the better option?

Comment: `overflow: auto` does not clear floats [follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22129343/why-does-overflow-auto-clear-floats-and-why-are-clear-floats-needed)

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects to resolve this question:

1. use **clear** properties, whether add :after to .outer class or add a real div as the last .outer container element can do;

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  width: 100%;
}
.outer:after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
}
.outer div {
  float: left;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    test1
    <br/> test1
    <br/> test1
  </div>
  <div>
    test2
    <br/> test2
    <br/> test2
  </div> 
</div>
```

2. Establish a new block formatting context. According to CSS2.1 specification, the way to create a new BFC is below:

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new block formatting contexts for their contents.

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  width: 100%;
  /* float and below overflow peoperties can both establish a new BFC */
  // float: left; 
  overflow: auto;
}

.outer div {
  float: left;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    test1
    <br/> test1
    <br/> test1
  </div>
  <div>
    test2
    <br/> test2
    <br/> test2
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow:auto`

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

.outer div {
  float: left;
  background-color: #0000ff;

}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    test1    <br/> test1
  </div>
  <div>
    test2    <br/> test2
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Method 1: use `<br style="clear: both">`

```css
.outer {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  width: 100%;
}

.outer div {
  float: left;
  background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    test1    <br/> test1
  </div>
  <div>
    test2    <br/> test2
  </div> 
  <br style="clear: both">
</div>
```

> Method 2 :use `overflow:hidden`

```
.outer {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;/*/<=========new/*/
}
```

> Mehod 3: use of `:after`

```
.outer:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```